# How to write an sqlite query for the following scenario?

Tags: sql, sqlite, reportviewer

Here is my query  for wpf form

```
Query = "select Cust_Id,Card_Number,Clients_Title,Address_Current,Phone_Number,Mobile_Number from Customer_New Where 1=1";
try
{
    if (txt_title.Text != "")
        Query += " and Clients_Title Like '%" + txt_title.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_address.Text != "")
        Query += " and Address_Current Like '%" + txt_address.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_phone.Text != "")
        Query += " and Phone_Number Like '%" + txt_phone.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_mobile.Text != "")
        Query += " and Mobile_Number Like '%" + txt_mobile.Text + "%'";
    if (cbo_location.Text != "")
        Query += " and AreaLocation Like '%" + cbo_location.Text + "%'";
}

catch { }
```

I want to report viewer query data like my wpf form .
Here is the query that i am trying in report viewer

```
SELECT        Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM            Customer_New
WHERE        (Clients_Title = @Clients_Title) OR
                         (Address_Current = @Address_Current) OR
                         (Phone_Number = @Phone_Number) OR
                         (Mobile_Number = @Mobile_Number) OR
                         (AreaLocation = @AreaLocation)
```

Can anyone tell me query for report viewer like wpf form .
Note :-

1. I cant use cant use C# controls in report viewer.Here in report
   viewer i can only use sql
2. What is needed in report viewers query  is:

   - When are all string of where clause are null then my report viewer
     should select query is:

     Query = "select Cust_Id,Card_Number,Clients_Title,Address_Current,Phone_Number,Mobile_Number from Customer_New ";
   - When any two string of where clause are not matching corresponding
     row db then nothing

   will be displayed

   - Lastly, selection will be made if just one condition of where clause
     is provided

Comment: Note : - I recently  found that sqlite don't support store procedure .So i have only option to make the query in report viewer data set .

Comment: Please explain what you mean "contrast in any where condition"

Comment: I thought that was what you meant.  That's not how boolean OR works.

Comment: (edited)  Contrast mean : If just one condition in where clause is not matches with remaining input fields of row or not found in db . Then nothing will be Selected .

Comment: i.e if user enter Clients_Title and enter his wrong Mobile_Number then nothing will be displayed ....If user just enter AreaLocation all client of that areas will be displayed.... If user enter no field then all records will be displayed

Comment: I answered your question already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT        Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM            Customer_New
    where        (CASE
        WHEN @Clients_Title != ''   THEN Clients_Title=@Clients_Title
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
      AND(CASE
        WHEN @Address_Current != '' THEN Address_Current =@Address_Current
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
              AND(CASE
        WHEN @Phone_Number != '' THEN Phone_Number=@Phone_Number
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
      AND(CASE
        WHEN @Mobile_Number != '' THEN Mobile_Number=@Mobile_Number
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
      AND(CASE
        WHEN @AreaLocation != '' THEN AreaLocation =@AreaLocation
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
```